# c++11 parameter pack wrong behaviour with Apple LLVM 7.0.0 but works with GCC-5.1

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, gcc, clang

Going from a previous version of this question, thanks to @Gene, I was now able to reproduce this behaviour using a simpler example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class Wrapper
{
  std::vector<int> const& bc;
public:
  Wrapper(std::vector<int> const& bc) : bc(bc) { }
  int GetSize() const { return bc.size(); }
};

class Adapter
{
  Wrapper wrapper;
public:
  Adapter(Wrapper&& w) : wrapper(w) { }
  int GetSize() const { return wrapper.GetSize(); }
};

template <class T>
class Mixin : public Adapter
{
public:
  //< Replace "Types ... args" with "Types& ... args" and it works even with Apple LLVM
  template <class ... Types>
  Mixin(Types ... args) : Adapter(T(args...)) { }
};

int main()
{
  std::vector<int> data;
  data.push_back(5);
  data.push_back(42);
  Mixin<std::vector<int>> mixin(data);
  std::cout << "data:  " << data.size() << "\n";
  std::cout << "mixin: " << mixin.GetSize() << "\n";
  return 0;
}
```

Result using Apple LLVM, tested with `-std=c++11` and `-std=c++14`:

```
data:  2
mixin: -597183193
```

Interestingly, I've tested this code also [@ideone](http://ideone.com/AGGbwj) which uses gcc-5.1 with C++14 enabled, and it works as expected!

```
data:  2
mixin: 2
```

**Why does `mixin.GetSize()` return a garbage value on Clang and why does it work with GCC-5.1?**

@Gene suggested that I'm using `Types ... args` which creates a temporary copy of the vector (and using `Types& ... args` makes it work with LLVM), but that copy would contain the same elements (thus also have the same size).

Comment: Yeah. The Problem is that `Types` is of the type `BaseContainer` and not as you wanted `BaseContainer const&`. So you are introducing a temporary copy which you then are referencing in _IteratorRef. You could change it to `Types const& ... args`. But I can't tell if this covers really 100% of all situations.

Comment: What is 'MSVC 17'? VC++ 2012?

Comment: Your question should contain [minimal code necessary to reproduce the problem](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), instead of linking to external sites which may change or become unavailable over time.

Comment: @Gene Thanks, it works when I use `Types const& ... args`! However, what I don't understand is the following: "you are introducing a temporary copy which you then are referencing in _IteratorRef" -- That temporary copy would contain the same elements! So even if the object is actually copied, it should print its items instead of none at all, no?

Comment: @M.M I'll update the question, now that I now the source of the problem is the parameter pack, this should become more easy.

Comment: @ildjarn Yes, sorry, I meant 11.0 (== 2012)

Comment: The Variable `args` is only valid inside of the `Mixin` constructor. But since you are keeping are reference to `args` you are trying to access it after it is destroyed.

Comment: @NiklasR : In that case, 17 was correct (17 is the compiler version, 11 is the IDE version, which no one cares about); just clarifying. :-]

Comment: @NiklasR, I agree with Gene, I think you have undefined behavior. It's often not a very good idea to make classes that have member variables of reference type, IMO, unless that class is intended to be very short-lived, i.e., destroyed at the end of the expression that creates it, or a visitor which will be created, applied, and then discarded, or something like this. Your code example seems to be just a subtle / convoluted way of binding a reference to a temporary.

Comment: Part of it may be that, you may think you are using perfect forwarding at the adaptor ctor `Adapter(Wrapper&& w) : wrapper(w) { }`, but this is not actually perfect forwarding here, that is passing an r-value reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a dangling reference, and `mixin.GetSize()` is yielding [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior):

- Inside of `Mixin`'s constructor, `T` = `std::vector<int>`, so `Adapter(T(args...))` is passing `Adapter`'s constructor a temporary `std::vector<int>`
- `Adapter`'s constructor parameter is a `Wrapper&&`, but we're passing it a `std::vector<int>&&`, so we invoke `Wrapper`'s implicit conversion constructor
- `Wrapper`'s constructor parameter is a `std::vector<int> const&`, and we're passing it a `std::vector<int>&&`; rvalues are allowed to bind to const-lvalue references, so this is *syntactically* fine and compiles fine, but in effect we're binding `Wrapper::bc` to a temporary
- Once construction is finished, the lifetime of the temporary created in `Mixin`'s constructor ends, and `Wrapper::bc` becomes a dangling reference; calls to `Adapter::GetSize` now yield UB

When `Mixin`'s constructor parameters are changed from `Types...` to `Types&...`, `Adapter(T(args...))` is **still** passing `Adapter`'s constructor a temporary `std::vector<int>`; it only *appears* to work because you are seeing a different manifestation of UB (likely the stack looks a bit different due to one fewer copies of `std::vector<int>` being made). I.e., **both** versions of the code are equally broken/wrong!

So, to answer this concretely:

> Why does `mixin.GetSize()` return a garbage value on Clang and why does it work with GCC-5.1?

Because the behavior of undefined behavior is undefined. ;-] Appearing to work is one possible outcome, but the code is still broken and the appearance of being correct is purely superficial.